# como prevenir sql injection symfony 1.4 e doctrine 1.2?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony

Oi,

Eu tenho um 3 inputs de pesquisas que fazem consultas ao banco de dados e me retornam os dados obtidos. Com isso um usuário mal intencionado pode burlar o meu sistema e obter outras informações.

Analisando o comportamento que uso para o usuário interagir com meu sistema, como poderia me prevenir contra esses ataques?

```
    $numeros = $request->getParameter('campoPesquisaNumero');
    $anos = $request->getParameter('campoPesquisaAno');
    $ementas = $request->getParameter('campoPesquisaEmenta');

    if($numero !== '' || $ano !== '' || $ementa !== '')
    {
          $pesquisar = Doctrine::getTable('tblicitacoes')
                          ->createQuery('l')
                          ->select('l.*')
                          ->where('l.numero LIKE \'%' . $numero . '%\' AND l.ano LIKE \'%' . $ano . '%\' AND l.ementa LIKE \'%'. $ementa .'%\' ')
                          ->andWhere('l.publicar = 1 OR l.publicar = "Y"')
                          ->orderBy('l.licitacoes_data DESC')
                          ->execute();
    }
```

Comment: Use Prepared Statements e Bind Parameters. Na documentação do Doctrine tem mais a respeito http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque as condições para os `LIKE`s como argumentos no método `execute`:

```
$pesquisar = Doctrine::getTable('tblicitacoes')
    ->createQuery('l')
    ->select('l.*')
    ->where('l.numero LIKE ? AND l.ano LIKE ? AND l.ementa LIKE ?')
    ->andWhere('l.publicar = 1 OR l.publicar = "Y"')
    ->orderBy('l.licitacoes_data DESC')
    ->execute(['%' . $numero . '%', '%' . $ano . '%', '%' . $ementa . '%']);
```

Dessa forma, o Doctrine sabe lidar com eventuais ataques do tipo SQL injection.

Comment: dessa maneira a query ficou bem melhor mesmo. ainda não fiz teste muito rígidos, mas até agora eu não consegui burlar a query.